# How to handle AWS-RDS connections within my application?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

I'm looking for some input on how to handle my connection to AWS-RDS. Should I open and close the connection each time I execute a query? Should I use a lambda function, and why?

I currently have it setup so the connection remains open and executions are handled from there. I have no connection closes or timeouts.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(db=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=user,
                       password=password)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I then have query executions throughout the code like such.

```
cur.execute("SELECT product, amount, total " +
              "FROM " + table +
            " WHERE po_date BETWEEN %s AND %s",
            (cur_month, next_month))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your application preferences.

Global Connection- If you create the connection at the global level, you save on the cost of opening the connection at each time you need to access the database, but you are using more memory on the database as it maintains the open connection. If the application does not close the connection on exit, the database must manually timeout this idle connection and kill it. You will need to add retry logic to the database to ensure the connection is still alive.

Connect Each Time - Added overhead of creating and closing the connection. Uses extra cpu on the client and db side to open and close the connection, but will keep the connection count lower.

As for using lambda, that completely depends on the application design. But, I would say yes, use it when you can!

If you want to use lambda to connect to a database, you will need to build a deployment package or a lambda layer to include the SQL client. Here are some links with step by step instructions to create these for python with pymysql. If needed, you can substitute the pymysql library with another SQL client using these same instructions.

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Package_Python

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Layer_Python

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find any documentation or posts for this problem anywhere. I was using sqlite before and there was plenty of information stating to open/close the connection each time.